# How can I extract suffix number from string

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings.
I'd like to extract a number suffix from a string.
Here is an example string array.

> let arrayData = [   '99ASD',   '01A',   '0134-A',   '78134:TSX' ]

How can I extract numbers from each string?

Comment: Use the available [`String`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#instance_methods) and [`RegExp`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#instance_methods) methods. See [Reference - What does this regex mean?](/q/22937618/4642212) and the [regex tag wiki](/tags/regex/info) and use regex debuggers like [RegEx101](//regex101.com/). What is the desired result? There are no numbers which are suffixes. Where are your attempts? Stack Overflow isn’t a free code-writing service.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not familiar with RegEx. Would you like to tell me the exact RegEx, plz?

Comment: No need for regex... `arrayData.map(s => parseInt(s, 10))`

Comment: Try this regex `/^\d+/` if you want to use regex to solve your problem.

Comment: FYI, if a token comes at the start of something it is a _prefix_. A [_suffix_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix) comes after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map):

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

and [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If `parseInt` encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified *radix*, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. `parseInt` truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

```js
let arrayData = [ '99ASD', '01A', '0134-A', '78134:TSX' ];
let arrayNum = arrayData.map(s => parseInt(s, 10));
console.log(arrayNum);
```